# Trim and Lowercase

Tags: java, methods, trim, lowercase

Every time I try doing the trim method and the lowercase method it doesn't show the way I want it.

```
sentence.trim();
sentence.toLowerCase();
System.out.println("\"" + sentence + "\"" + " ---> ");
```

For example, if I input " Hello World! ", it will print out " Hello World! " and not use any of the methods.

Comment: Strings are immutable. Say this 100 times and write this on the chalk board 100 times.

Comment: `int i = 7; i * 2; System.out.println(i);` <- why does this print 7 and not 14?

Comment: It is supposed to be "i *= 2" or in other words "i = i * s", it is because "i * 2" has to be stored in a double or int value like we have here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to store the value returned:

```
sentence = sentence.trim().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do

```
sentence = sentence.trim();
sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad you helped me!

Answer (score 1):

They don't trim or lowercase "in-place"

You could just put it in the print statement, though

```
System.out.println("\"" + sentence.trim().toLowerCase() + "\"" + " ---> ");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!